# How to log errors into file in php?

Tags: php

I started the beginner with php. I need to get errors that append in my website I use below code for log errors into file but do not work. This has no any error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo "My first PHP script!";
error_log( "Hello, errors!" );

?>
</body>
</html>
```

What is problem?

Comment: what do you mean by "This has no any error." ? Where you expect it to be?

Comment: when reload page display on page  My first PHP script! .  with out any error

Comment: because there is no errors in this script. From docs, by default `error_log()`  "sent to PHP's system logger, using the Operating System's system logging mechanism or a file, depending on what the error_log configuration directive is set to"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above code, you need to also instruct php to log errors.  Add the following directive

```
$path =$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/file.txt';//tell php where to save your error logs

ini_set('log_errors',1);//logs errors 

ini_set('error_log',$path); //override php's default error log directory
```

Comment: I change my code such as  this but do not write error into file <?php
$path =$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/log.txt';
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('log_errors',1);
ini_set('error_log',$path);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require('dd.ir');

?>

Comment: Does the path variable exist??

Comment: @programmer138200 to display errors `ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` is enough. You just don't see any errors because there is no such in your script. `error_log()` doesn't create an error, it just logs it.

Comment: The error log name is kinda confusing you.  All it does is to log the string parameter to a file.  Not specifically an error

Comment: @programmer138200 if you want to log errors into file with `error_log()` set second param "message_type" to 3 and third param file where you would like to write `error_log("Error message", 3, 'my_errors.log');`